# PHP: Multiple Drop Down Options tied to multiple functions

Tags: php, forms, function, drop-down-menu

This is more of a PHP design question.  Basically, I'm going to have a form with a drop down menu and a submit button.  I am going to have an infinite amount of drop down options; obviously, not an infinite, but there's basically going to be a drop down menu with ALOT of options.  These "options" are individual reports that I want to run.

So, the user selects from the drop down menu, for example, "Articles without approval", which I want to tie to a function in my functions.php file that runs the SQL for this and outputs everything nicely in a table.

My problem is, how do I do this without have a huge if/else statement in my main document that that basically says "If the submit button is equal to "Articles without approval", do this", etc etc for every drop down option.  I need something dynamic, without a bunch of if/else statements.

Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to wrap all of your app into a framework that might be more conducive to this sort of thing, you'll probably find it easier to call the function dynamically.

Suppose you had functions called  `articlesWithoutApproval()` and `articlesWithApproval()`. Then, you could do something like this:

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
    <select name="reportName">
        ...
        <option value="articlesWithoutApproval">Articles without approval</option>
        <option value="articlesWithApproval">Articles with approval</option>
        ...
    </select>
</form>
```

Then, in `handler.php`, do:

```
<?php
function articlesWithoutApproval(){ ... }
function articlesWithApproval(){ ... }

// clean variables, etc

if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

    $func_name = $_POST['reportName']; // equal to "articlesWithoutApproval"
    echo $func_name(); // call the function dynamically
    // above evaluates to `echo articlesWithoutApproval();` etc
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a whirl, seems pretty straight forward and very easily to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Have a mapping of options to functions, such as...

```
$reportsToFunctions = array(
   'without_approval' => 'withoutApproval',
   ...
);
```

Which you can then look up and run the function.

Comment: Can you reiterate on this?  I've never done this, so if you have some insight or even a resource that documents this, I'd be very much appreciative.

Comment: Would it be something like `$reportsToFunctions['without_approval'];`, which would be called via a `if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && $_POST['submit'] ) ) {`, like what Ryan posted?  You are just storing these in an array, correct?

Comment: @drewrockshard [Ryan has it covered pretty well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644222/php-multiple-drop-down-options-tied-to-multiple-functions/5644258#5644258) :)

Comment: That's what I was thinking, pretty slick!